# How to re-save data in UITableVIew without causing any duplicates of the same UITextVIew in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, textview, tableview

Userdefaults-saved data is passed from my `TextViewCotroller` to `TextViewTableController` successfully, but not perfectly successful. This is because when my `TextView`, which has some data already, is re-saved, it causes a duplicate.

*For example, if the firstly saved data is like "hello, I like bagels" and if I edit it to like "hello, I like bagels and chololate cookies" and re-save it,
At the 0 index of my TableView is "hello, I like bagels and chololate cookies" 
At the 1 index of my TableView is "hello, I like bagels"*

When this is repeatedly done, there are multiple duplicates of the same text  in my `TableView`. This is so annoying that I really want to detect the cause of this issue. However, I have no idea of fixing this bug.

**TextTableViewController：**

```
  class TextTableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func saveTextData() -> [String] {
    if let textData = userTextDataSave.array(forKey: "txtData") as? [String] {
        return textData
    }
    return []
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return saveTextData().count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellForText", for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.textLabel?.text = saveTextData()[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    tableView.reloadData()
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        // Delete the row from the data source
        removeHistory(index: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "text",sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "text") {
        let subVC: TextViewController = (segue.destination as? TextViewController)!
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
        subVC.textFromCell = saveTextData()[(indexPath?.row)!]
    }
}
```

}

**TextViewController and functions for saving text data:**

```
func save(){

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "titile", message: "save?", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let noAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { Void in
    })

    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { Void in

        self.addTextData(text: self.myTextView.text)
    })

    alert.addAction(noAction)
    alert.addAction(okAction)
    present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)

}

func saveTextData() -> [String] {
    if let textData = userTextDataSave.array(forKey: "txtData") as? [String] {
        return textData
    }
    return []

}

func addTextData(text: String) {
    var data = saveTextData()
    for d in data {

        if d == "" {
            return
        }
    }
    data.insert(text, at: 0)
    userTextDataSave.set(text, forKey: "txtData")
    userTextDataSave.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: why you are insert text in array  before set data to userdefaults.?

Comment: what do you mean? How am I doing wrong? Could you show me an appropriate code?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Why are you saving the text every time at zeroth index? It seems that you haven't shared the complete code.

Comment: @adeel I edited and add some more information. If you still find it inadequate, please point out what code in what section do you think you need to know.

Comment: add the `numberOfRowsInSection` method first. Then please explain what are you trying to achieve and if possible add a screenshot of the screen so that I can get a clear idea of how things are working.

Comment: you are saving a string in this line `userTextDataSave.set(text, forKey: "txtData")`. How do you expect to get an array of strings in this line `userTextDataSave.array(forKey: "txtData") as? [String]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
   func addTextData(text: String) {
var data = saveTextData()
for d in data {

    if d == "" {
        return
    }
    if d == text {
        return
    }
}

userTextDataSave.set(text, forKey: text)
userTextDataSave.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: Does it mean I should delete data.insert()?

Comment: No. But I want to create different textdata. So only already created text data should not be re-created

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: Do you mean I should write like

Comment: func addTextData(text: String) {
        
        
        var data = saveTextData()
        
        for d in data {
            if d == "" {
                return
            }

        }
        

        userTextDataSave.set(data, forKey: "txtData")
        userTextDataSave.synchronize()
        
        
    }

Comment: All existing data is gone when I changed to this code. Why? Btw I updated my post and the saveTextData() returns array. Is this related to my bug perfaps?

Comment: do you want to edited text is shows in first index ?

Comment: I do not care about the order of text. I just I do  not want to make any duplicates. If I create a new text data, it should be saved and when it is edited again, then the text data should not be a duplicate. Want this to function like  the built-in note app in iPhone.

Comment: Why do you use it as a key? Isn't it like I should connect returned value with a key and put it in an array and display values to UITableVIew?